# how to set value center in each column export datatable pdfhtml

Tags: datatable, datatables

I have code to export datatable pdfhtml like this

```js
$('#example3').DataTable( {
  dom: 'lBfrtip',  
  buttons: [
      {
         extend: 'pdfHtml5',
         title: 'Data Cucian Kain Cartiva '+d,
         orientation:'portrait',
         download: 'open',
         orientation:'landscape',
         customize: function(doc) {
           doc.content.forEach(function(item) {
             if (item.table) {
                item.table.widths = [40, 40, '*','*','*'] 
             } 
           })
         }
      }
  ]
} );
```

and result like this
[image]
I want the data in each column be in the center instead of on the left.

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```js
customize: function(doc) {
   doc.defaultStyle.alignment = 'center';
   ...
}
```

Think it explains itself :) Your code working in a jsfiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/ccdn6g2v/**